# Why does the review system not prevent reviewing questions that are just now rewiewed by another one?

Tags: discussion, bug, review-page

Just a few minutes ago I was rewiewing a first post. Another one did also rewiew the same post and closed his review first, so that my review with more correcting was deleted.

Why does the review system not prevent reviewing questions that are just now rewiewed by another one?

I think there should be no fight for first clicking "I'm Done" but to get complete reviewed and so better posts ... If one is reviewing a post no one more should be able to review the same post until reviewing is finished.

What do you think about that?

Comment: You mean editing, not reviewing, right? There is a dedicated review system under http://tex.stackexchange.com/review, which you might not be able to access yet. For the editing process there is already a feature request or bug report either here or on the main meta.sx site.